# VB.net Checking if value exists in Database table

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

This is my code..

```
Private Sub btnSaveGrade_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSaveGrade.Click

    If Me.TblStudentsBindingSource.Filter = "StudentNo= '" & StudentNoTextBox.Text & " ' " Then
        Me.Validate()
        Me.TblResultsBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.InfoSystemDataSet1)
        Me.TblResultsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.InfoSystemDataSet1.tblResults)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Hello")
    End If

End Sub
```

My aim is that when I press the button to save data to my database.
I only want it to save, if the student number entered matches a student number in a column of my database.

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you want to have a database *Relationship* that enforces *Referential Integrity*. A web search for "Microsoft Access relationship" should point you in the right direction.

Comment: No. That's just silly. My problem is not in relation to my database tables. I basically need an if statement that says..."If txtStudentNo.Text is not a record in tblStudents Then"

Answer (score 0):

For this specific case what you have to do is create a **SELECT** query on your .xsd file use the option **SELECT which returns a single value** after the query is created you have to run the query on the if statement i.e:

```
If not Me.TblResultsTableAdapter.myquery(StudentNoTextBox.Text) Is Nothing Then
    Msgbox("Hello")
End If
```

Comment: Ok thank you! How would I go about creating this SELECT query? Don't understand how I create it on a .xsd file? Apologies I am new to VB.net and Databases

Comment: If you use Visual Studio when you add a datasource the .xsd file is created automatically. On the solution explorer you have to double click to open that file and from there you can right click the table adapter you want to create the query. You must know how to create SQL queries. Once you create your query there the rest is piece of cake